# Selenium Java: With TestNG, Not executing 2nd test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gOiu.png)

Please help me to fix the below issue in Selenium WebDriver with Java.

I am validating eComm web based application. I have couple of test cases.
1. Sign in to the application
2. Add to item to the cart. This test case is a continuation of first test case. It means that after sign in, user is gonna add the item to the cart.

I have 2 class files, In that I have given @Test condition in both the class files.

In CommonFunctions class file, I am lauching browser in @BeforeSuite section. And closing the browser in @AfterSuite section.

I am doing it in Page object model and executing from TestNG XML.

On running the suite, First test case is getting passed. When it comes to the second test case (In the @Test condition present in the 2nd class file), the in it entering into the @Test section but getting failed immediately with out any reason.

I have tried with Implicit, Explicit wait and even thread.sleep as well. But no luck. Please can some one take a look and suggect me.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't reuse the driver.

Create it in @BeforeMethod then quit it in @AfterMethod and you should not meet any issues.

**Update answering a comment question below:**

#### In general it's not a good idea to have the tests depending on each other.

Regardless of how special you think your case is, you should never do it if you want to keep your dignity.

This does not neccessarily mean that you can't reuse 'logic' in tests, it just means that you should not expect any other test to have executed before the current one.

Let's put some thought about it:

1. Why would you want to do it at first place?
2. What is the effect that you're seeking?

My blind-guess answers are:

1. You want to have the login test executed first.
2. This will help you avoid repeating the same login code in all of the remaining tests, and you save time from starting/stopping the driver.

If my guesses are correct, then I can tell you that it's perfectly normal to want those things, and that everyone who ever needed to write more than 2 tests has been there

You may ask:

1. Am I not trying to achieve the same thing?
2. Where is my mistake then?

The following answers can be considered brief and quite insufficient compared to the truth that lies beneath, but I think they will serve you as a good starting point for where you're heading at.

1. Yes, you're trying to achieve the same thing.
2. Your approach can't be called mistake, but negliance - you're trying to write automated tests with Selenium while you lack basic coding skills. It's actualy not so bad, because you didn't knew what you're getting into, but after reading this you have the choice of either letting it slip or begin the journey to personal improvement. Take some time to learn Java - a really good starter would be the 'Thinking in Java' book. Do make the exercises after each chapter and the experience that you'll gain will be priceless. The book will help you get familiar with the Java language features and good idea of how code organization works.

Enough with the general notes, below is a simple guide for you to follow in implementing v0.1 of your newly-born **'automation project'**. 
(Yes, it is '*project*' and '*framework*' is having completely different meaning,  to be clear.)

#### First you need to decide how to approach the page objects.

(Based on my own experience)

- the best way to do it is to keep all the business-logic inside the page objects and by *business-logic* I mean:

  - all the methods that perform some action,
  - and all the methods that retrieve some data.
- Examples include doSomething / getSometing / setSomething / isSomething / canSomething / waitSomething and so on.
- You should not be doing any *assertions* inside the page objects
- You should **never** throw AssertionError from your page objects
- If you need to throw something from page-object method/constructor just

  - throw IllegalArgumentException
  - or RuntimeException.
- All the assertions should happen ***exclusively*** in the test-method-body
- You should never write 'assert...' statement outside @Test method
- You can have Util classes to do some data transformations

  - but do not ever write assertion logic inside them
  - rather expose methods with boolean/other return type and assert on their result.

### The following example is one of the best I've ever seen:

```
// Don't do this:
ColorVerifications.assertAreSame(pen.getColor(), ink.getColor());

// If you do, you'll eventually end-up having to write this:
ColorVerifications.assertAreNotSame(pen.getColor(), ink.getColor());


// Do this instead:
Assert.isTrue(ColorUtil.areSame(pen.getColor(), ink.getColor());

// Then you can actually 'reuse' the logic that's already in the Assert class:
Assert.isFalse(ColorUtil.areSame(pen.getColor(), ink.getColor());

// NOTE: Regarding the term "code reuse" 
// - it is NOT referring to "reusing your own code"
// - it IS referring to "reusing all the existing code"
```

The idea is to clearly communicate both the assert intention and how the check is done.

Always keep the logic of '***checking***' and '***asserting***' separate, becuse those words are having different *semantics*.

It is really important to put a good amount of thinking when naming classes / methods / variables - really!

Don't be afraid to rename it when you come up with a better fit - go for it on the spot!

#### Now back to our page obects and login stuff - I won't be diving much into it but, you'll get where I'm going at.

- Carefully organize the @Test methods in separate classes
- Keep the ones that need common setup in the same class
- Keep the number of test-class methods that are not annotated with @Test to the minimum
- Do not inherit between test classes to reuse logic other than

  - Outputs/Results folders preparaton/colletion/archiving
  - Logs/Reports initialization/disposal
  - Driver creation/cleanup
- **In general: prefer composition to inheritance**
- Put other logic in the page objects / util classes and reuse them
- Have a base DriverWrapper class for the generic UI checks/interactions
- Have a base PageObject class that is hosting a DriverWrapper member
- Don't use the @FindBy / PageFactory model (you'r life will be happier)
- Use static final By locators instead
- Log **everything**!

  - logging is not included in the examples
  - but do assume every method's first line is logging the method name and the passed arguments
  - always remember - your log is your best friend
  - Reading what happened in the log takes considerably less time than manually debugging the code (which is pratically re-running it at half-speed)
  - You are writing atuomation code, not production code so you can nevver be wrong when logging additional info.
  - Except for the cases of passwords and confidential data

    - those you should never log.

#### Now that you have been thaught some basic ideas, lets dive into code:

### Page basics

Sample DriverWrapper:

```
class DriverWrapper {

    protected final WebDriver driver;

    public DriverWrapper(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = Objects.requireNotNull(driver, "WebDriver was <null>!");
    }

    // it's okay to have 'checked exceptions' declared by all wait* methods
    // but it is tottaly not okay to have 'checked exceptions' for the others
    public WebElement waitForVisibleElement(By locator, int timeoutMillis) 
        throws TimeoutException { // <- the 'checked exception'
            return new WebDriverWait(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                .until(
                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy(locator)
                );
    }

    public boolean isVisible(By locator, int timeoutMillis){
        try{
            return waitForVisibleElement(locator, timeoutMillis) != null;
        catch(TimeoutException ignored){
            return false;
        }
    }


    // .get(String url){...}
    // .click(By locator){... elementToBeClickable(locator) ....}
    // .typeInto(bool shouldLog, By locator, CharSequence... keys){...}
    // .typeInto(By locator, CharSequence... keys){typeInto(true, locator, keys);}
    // you got the idea ;)
}
```

Sample PageObject:

```
class PageObject{

    protected final DriverWrapper driver;

    public PageObject(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = new DriverWrappr(driver);
    }

}
```

Sample LoginPage:

```
class LoginPage extends PageObjet{

    // NOTE: keep the locators private
    private static final By USERNAME_INPUT = By.id("usernameInput");
    private static final By PASSWORD_INPUT = By.id("passwordInput");
    private static final By LOGIN_BUTTON = By.id("loginButton");
    private static final By ERROR_MESSAGE = By.id("errorMessage");

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public LoginPage goTo(){ 
        driver.get(url);
        return this;
    }

    public void loginAs(String user, String pass){
        // NOTE: 
        //      Do not perform navigation (or other actions) under the hood!
        //      Resist the urge to call goTo() here!
        //      Page object methods should be transparent about what they do.
        //      This results in better level of control/transparency in the tests.

        driver.typeInto(USERNAME_INPUT, user);
        driver.typeInto(PASSWORD_INPUT, pass);
        driver.click(LOGIN_BUTTON);
    }

    public boolean isErrorMessageVisible(int timeoutMillis){
        // NOTE: We delegate the call to the driver
        //       Allowing the page-object to later define it's own isVisible method
        //       Without having collision with driver methods.

        return driver.isVisible(ERROR_MESSAGE, timeoutMillis);
    }
}
```

### Infrastructure basics

Sample DriverManager class:

```
class DriverManager{

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }

    public static void setDriver(WebDriver driver){
        // NOTE: Don't do null checks here.
        DriverManager.driver = driver;
    }

    public static WebDriver createDriver(String name){
         //...
         return new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Sample TestBase class:

```
class TestBase{
    // NOTE: just define the methods, do not annotate them.

    public static void setUpDriver(){
        // In v0.1 we'll be sharing the driver between tests in same class
        // Assuming the tests will not be running in parallel.
        // For v1.0 you can improve the model after reading about test-listeners

        WebDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver();
        if(driver != null){
            return;
        }

        driver = DriverManager.createDriver("chrome");
        DriverManager.setDriver(driver);
    }

    public static void tearDownDriver(){
        WebDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver();
        if(driver != null){
            driver.quit();
            DriverManager.setDriver(null);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Finally - a test class:

```
class LoginTests extends TestBase{

    private LoginPage loginPage;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass(){
        setUpDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass(){
        tearDownDriver();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        // actions, that are common for all test cases in the class
        loginPage = new LoginPage(DriverManager.getDriver());
        loginPage.goTo();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
        // dispose the page objets to ensure no local data leftovers
        loginPage = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGivenExistingCredentialsWhenLoginThenNoError(){
        loginPage.loginAs("TestUser", "plain-text password goes here");
        boolean errorHere = loginPage.isErrorMessageVisible(30 * 1000);
        Assert.assertFalse(errorHere, "Unexpected error during login!");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGivenBadCredentialsWhenLoginThenErrorShown(){
        loginPage.loginAs("bad", "guy");
        boolean errorHere = loginPage.isErrorMessageVisible(30 * 1000);
        Assert.assertTrue(errorHere, "Error message not shown!");
    }
}
```

### That's all there is to it.

Hope you enjoyed the ride.

Comment: Yes that is for single test case. What if i want to execute multiple test cases with the same driver instance. This would happen when u want to test a continuous flow. Means, 2nd test case is continuation of 1st test case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is getting failed for some exception and the stack trace is not getting printed somehow. Try explicitly getting it printed by:

```
@Test
public void SecondTestCase(){
    try{
        yourSecondTestCase;
    }
    catch(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```